# Core Data can I re-fault images out of memory?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm developing in iOS 6.1 and working my way through Core Data.

In the book I'm studying, "**Core Data for iOS: Developing Data-Driven Applications for the iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch**", by Isted & Harrington, they are discussing (on pages 170-1) how to store images in Core Data and I'm doing something quite similar.

The author says something that I'm not sure what he's alluding to.  Quote:

> You need to make sure to re-fault container objects to avoid keeping
>   the image data in memory.

I think this might apply to me.

I have two types of objects; photoSm and photoLg.

The image in each photoSm objects is small (180x230) whereas the one in the corresponding (linked by relationship) photoLg object is larger at (720x920).

I fetch the entire photoSm group of objects and it loads quickly and I can zoom back and forth through the images with a slider with no noticeable delays.

If the user stops moving the slider, a timer triggers after a short pause and I follow the relationship from the displayed image's photoSm object to the photoLg object and thus load the photoLg object.  Once loaded, I replace the lower resolution image displayed from the photoSm object with the higher resolution one from the photoLg object.

It all works beautifully.

I think I've read that once I follow the relationship from photoSm to photoLg and fault photoLg into memory, that it will stay indefinitely.  That could clutter memory up as the number of photos grow.

So, I'd like to know how to flush the photoLg objects back out of memory.  Or 're-fault' them as Isted & Harrington say.

Or maybe this is all a red herring and Core Data will automatically re-fault them as it needs space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same book page 167, "refreshObject: mergeChanges:" will convert it back to a fault object.

Comment: Only if `mergeChanges` is `NO`